# Setting properties from another class

Tags: c#, class, properties

I want to pinpoint I'm totally new to C# and I'm just testing around to get a grasp of this language.

Want I want to achieve is to just console-print in a secondary window a couple of values I've set in the MainWindow.

This is a function contained in the MainWindow class, triggered by a button click.

```
private void ValidationExecuted(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        // If the validation was successful, let's open a new window.
        GeneratorWindow generatorWindow = new GeneratorWindow();
        generatorWindow.TextBlockName1.Text = this.tbPoints.Text;
        generatorWindow.TextBlockName2.Text = this.tbPDC.Text;

        int.TryParse(this.tbPoints.Text, out int numberOfPoints);
        int.TryParse(this.tbPDC.Text, out int pdc);

        // Those lines correctly print the values I've inserted in the TextBoxes.
        Console.WriteLine(numberOfPoints);
        Console.WriteLine(pdc);

        generatorWindow.NumberOfPoints = numberOfPoints;
        generatorWindow.MainPDC = pdc;
        generatorWindow.Show();

        // Resetting the UI.
        this.validator = new Validator();
        this.grid.DataContext = this.validator;
        eventArgs.Handled = true;
    }
```

Now my secondary window:

```
public partial class GeneratorWindow : Window
{
    /// <inheritdoc />
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="T:ABB_Rapid_Generator.GeneratorWindow" /> class.
    /// </summary>
    public GeneratorWindow()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        // Those lines just print a pair of 0.
        Console.WriteLine(this.NumberOfPoints);
        Console.WriteLine(this.MainPDC);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the number of points.
    /// </summary>
    public int NumberOfPoints { private get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the main PDC.
    /// </summary>
    public int MainPDC { private get; set; }
}
```

As you can see in the code comments, the `Console.WriteLine()` contained in the main class are correctly working. Moreover I can assign my custom values to the TextBlocks contained in the other class. On the contrary, the `Console.WriteLine()` lines in the secondary class are just outputting a couple of zeros.

What have I been missing?

Comment: When the GeneratorWindow is made it will default to 0 for the 2 values, when you update them  you never output them

Comment: Write a method in GeneratorWindow Print() with the WriteLine() or something, call it after the value have been updated from the MainWondow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that in `GeneratorWindow` you are writing to the console in the *constructor* method, so the values are being output **before you are changing them**.

The only way you can really get that output to work would be to pass the values as parameters of the constructor and set them (in the constructor) before you do the console output. Though there doesn't seem any logical reason to go down that path.

For example:

```
public GeneratorWindow(int numberOfPoints, int mainPdc)
{
    this.InitializeComponent();

    this.NumberOfPoints = numberOfPoints;
    this.MainPDC = mainPdc;

    Console.WriteLine(this.NumberOfPoints);
    Console.WriteLine(this.MainPDC);
}
```

---

Alternatively, if you want to see the values after you set them, then you will need to move your console outputs to another function that you call **after** you have set the values.

For example, add this function to `GeneratorWindow`:

```
public void OutputValues()
{
    Console.WriteLine(this.NumberOfPoints);
    Console.WriteLine(this.MainPDC);
}
```

Which you can then call after you have set the values in your other class:

```
GeneratorWindow generatorWindow = new GeneratorWindow();

generatorWindow.NumberOfPoints = numberOfPoints;
generatorWindow.MainPDC = pdc;

generatorWindow.OutputValues();
```

Answer (score 1):

you can add a parameter-ize constructor to do so

```
public partial class GeneratorWindow : Window
{
    //Private members
    int m_numberOfPoints;
    int m_mainPDC;

    /// <inheritdoc />
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="T:ABB_Rapid_Generator.GeneratorWindow" /> class.
    /// </summary>
    public GeneratorWindow(int mainPDC,int numberOfPoints)
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.m_mainPDC = mainPDC;
        this.m_numberOfPoints = numberOfPoints;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the number of points.
    /// </summary>
    public int NumberOfPoints 
    { 
      get{ return m_numberOfPoints; }
      set{ m_numberOfPoints = values; }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the main PDC.
    /// </summary>
    public int MainPDC
    { 
      get{ return m_mainPDC; }
      set{ m_mainPDC= values; }
    }

    public void Print()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(this.NumberOfPoints);
        Console.WriteLine(this.MainPDC);
    }
}
```

also this is a constructor so it will be just called at

```
GeneratorWindow generatorWindow = new GeneratorWindow();//here
```

Change the secondary window call to

```
 generatorWindow  = new GeneratorWindow(pdc,numberOfPoints);
 generatorWindow.Print();
```

Also, your code is not done in a good way IMO, why set values like this?

```
   generatorWindow.TextBlockName1.Text = this.tbPoints.Text;
   generatorWindow.TextBlockName2.Text = this.tbPDC.Text;
```

> If you have private variables set just as above sample you can perform all converting, printing and , receiving console output in same class.you'll need to just call the constructor and print method.

Comment: Thank you for your insight.

Comment: @Davide3i glad to help

Answer (score 1):

Answer above is correct, but there is an alternative.
You can use setter methods like `setNumberOfPoints`, `setMainPDC` and print co console after setting the value. So in `ValidationExecuted` you call for a function to set variable, and in that function after setting variable you print it to console. But don't forget to remove printing to console from `constructor`

Comment: (This post does not seem to provide a [quality answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to the question. Please either edit your answer, or just post it as a comment to the other answer).